# form_for from deep nested hash

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, nested-attributes

i am looking for a way bring in a hash, and use it with form_for.  i was playing around with Hashie::Mash to make a pseudo object, which seems to work ok.  but it ran into problems with deep nested keys.

```
@mash = Hashie::Mash.new({:level_one => "foo", :same_level => {:level_two => "bar"}})
```

then with form_for...

```
= form_for @mash do |m|
  = m.text_field :level_one
  = m.fields_for :same_level do |s|
    = s.text_field :level_two
```

the text field for level_one gets populated with "foo", but level_two is blank.

essentially i need to wrap the hash in a some type of object, but how do i handle the nested hashes?  i am trying to load settings from a yaml file, modify them in a form, then save them back out.

Comment: Does your `@mash.same_level.level_two` property returns the string? Are you sure that this init hash is properly translated into nested properties? Rails-way would be `same_level_attributes` if you used `accepts_nested_attributes_for`, but maybe you have defined an accessor yourself?

Comment: yes @mash.same_level.level_two returns "bar", but isnt accepts_nested_attributes_for only for active record?